# Passing input on one pin of FPGA straight out to another output pin for monitoring

Tags: vivado, timing-analysis, constraints, artix-series-fpga

I need to monitor a signal as it is going into the FPGA, tracking down a potential noisy input or slow rising signal issue.  I want to use an external oscilloscope to see what the FPGA sees (as opposed to the internal chip scope), so I thought I could just do this :

[image]

However, this creates a timing violation that I don't understand.  I get a WNS of -3.758ns -- what setup/hold time does the tool think I need to meet here?  This is not going into a latch or anything, just connecting two pins internally (one in , one out).  Am I violating the setup time for the FPGA's IO buffer?  If so, what are my options?
All I'm trying to do is to monitor a signal as it "enters" the FPGA by echoing it out another pin.  I can of course connect the scope directly to the input pin by soldering a wire to it, but I do not want to do that.  The other pin I can use to monitor the input signal is available and goes out to an easily accessible connector.

***********Edit ********
Timing violation:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to show more details about the timing violation, including the path that is indicated in the timing analyzer? There might be hints as to what constraint is acting upon the path in this case

Comment: It's easy to see why you want to do this, what may be less initially obvious is how uselessly artificial this would actually be.  You won't get an analog output, but a digital one, however a combinatorial path through an FPGA is so unusual the tools are very unhappy with the request.  And it may not be as meaningful as you think.  Really what you should do is examine the version registered with whatever clock the internal logic is using - output *that* if you like.  Maybe there's a way to waive the check, or maybe you can register it with a very fast clock...

Comment: What FPGA and software environment are you using? This should be possible anyway, more context on the error as well would be necessary to help you.

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisStratton. The signal I want to monitor is a signal whose edge clocks an instantiated up/down counter (i'm measuring a quadrature encoder) Yes, the signal will be digital, that is what I want to see --I want to see how the input signal is "interpreted" by the FPGA- is it creating multiple edges internally due to a slow transition, etc..I could latch it, but then I'm at the mercy of the clock with which I sample it. Echoing it,  I can use a scope to see the input to the FPGA, and how it is really seen inside the FPGA.

Comment: Thank you, @DylanM, I'm using Vivado (2018.2).

Comment: Thank you, @nanofarad, see the question edit.

Comment: @jrive For whatever reason, the tool is associating that whole signal as being synchronous to your VIRTUAL_clk_out1_NF_CommTest_..., while you don't actually need that clock. You could ignore the path altogether using [TIG constraints](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Timing-Analysis/How-can-I-tell-timing-to-ignore-this-path/m-p/306785/highlight/true#M4044), knowing that the path delay is going to be an issue along with the things Chris Stratton mentioned above.

Comment: Probably the simplest option is to find out how to express "don't care" or "TIG" (Timing Ignore) in the timing constraints, and add such a constraint from that input pin to that output pin (or on that internal signal).  Details depend on your FPGA toolchain : read the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unconstrain the output (set a false path) and the timing violation will go away.

In Vivado you put these in the .xdc file for your design. More about that here: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Timing-Analysis/What-does-quot-set-false-path-through-quot-do/td-p/397531

`set_false_path` is part of the group of `tcl` commands called SDC, short for Synopsys Design Constraints. Xilinx, Altera and other FPGA vendors adopted SDC some time ago; I recommend this method over the older 'TIG' approach.

SDC is very powerful and a bit opaque, but once you learn it you will have much better control over your design, especially when it comes to constraining I/O timing.

Comment: Good answer, +1.  You could also just ignore the warning, as you know better than the compiler that this signal is unrelated to other clocks and is just for a simple observational diagnostic.